# How can I iterate over and print the properties of a Spring Environment object

Tags: spring

org.springframework.core.env.Environment seems to have a getProperty method, but nothing to iterate over all of the properties. Was this intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is [intentional](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10241).

> The PropertyResolver interface and PropertySource class are
>   intentionally limited in this respect so that they can be backed by
>   providers that might not have the ability to iterate keys.